# Path.GetTempPath() method returns UserTempPath with GUID in the end when using Revit 2020

Tags: c#, .net, revit, .net-4.7.2

Most of the applications consuming my add-in return "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\" path. But one application is returning "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\1affa5dd-2f26-4c96-9965-7a78f5c76321\". The GUID in the end changes every time I launch the application.

The application that I am running my add-in from are Revit 2015-2020. Revit versions 2015-2019 return the correct path. But Revit 2020 is returning the path with GUID appended in the end. The code remains the same.

```
    public static string GetLocalFilePath(string sourceUri, string fileName, string extension)
    {
        string[] sasTokenSeparated = sourceUri.Split('?');
        string[] uriParts = sasTokenSeparated[0].Split('/');
        string documentId = uriParts[uriParts.Length - 2];
        documentId = documentId.Split('.')[0];
        string extensionWithDot = string.Empty;
        if (!extension.StartsWith("."))
        {
            extensionWithDot = "." + extension;
        }
        else
        {
            extensionWithDot = extension;
        }
        string localPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), documentId, fileName + fileExtension);
        return localPath;
    }
```

I am expecting the path,
"C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\"

While I am actually getting path,
"C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\1affa5dd-2f26-4c96-9965-7a78f5c76321\"

Comment: That's probably due to Revit defining its own `%TMP/TEMP%` Environment Variable.

Comment: I have checked in Watch Window. The values that I have pasted are being returned from Path.GetTempPath() method. DocumentId is appended after the value returned from that method.
localPath value in the above is "C:\Users\umar.aslam\AppData\Local\Temp\1affa5dd-2f26-4c96-9965-7a78f5c76321\4f5dce0b-e8d4-a4ea-1285-7765fd82fde1"

Comment: Possible alternative would be: `Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOCALAPPDATA"), "Temp")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [this forum link](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/revit-2020-temp-path-changes-every-session/td-p/8759058), `Revit 2020` alters the value returned as per what you are seeing.

> Since Revit 2020 the requested temp path contains an additional guid
>   at the end of the path, which changes after every restart of Revit(ie.
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\84ae8c0d-197b-4b44-b8d3-8823fabbba4f).
>   It seems like Revit changes the temp path for the scope of the
>   application.

Answer (score 2):

I made an small fix wich splits the Path by the '\' character and composes a string until the word 'Temp', it works but **consider it a concept**.

```
private void concept()
        {
            string fullpath = Path.GetTempPath();
            string[] ph = fullpath.Split('\\');
            bool fix = false;
            string fixedpath = "";
            foreach (string word in ph)
            {

                if (fix == false)
                {
                    fixedpath = fixedpath + word + @"\";
                }
                if (word.ToLower().Equals("temp"))
                {
                    fix = true;
                }

            }
            MessageBox.Show(fixedpath);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
Path.Combine(
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile),
  "AppData",
  "Local",
  "Temp");
```